Railteam/HOTNAT when the next train is the following morning - can I claim for hotel costs?
I was recently stuck in Brussels overnight when my DB ICE train from Germany was cancelled. DB did eventually get me to Brussels, but it wasn't in time to make my Eurostar connection to London. This meant I had to pay for a hotel for the night, because there were no more trains to London that evening. HOTNAT meant Eurostar put me on a train in the morning without needing to buy a new ticket.
It's not possible to buy a through ticket for my whole journey, so the DB section and the Eurostar were separate tickets - which doesn't matter for HOTNAT. But if the whole thing had been one ticket, DB would be obliged to pay for the overnight accommodation. I can definitely get some delay compensation from DB, but am I entitled to any refund from DB for the extra expenses?
(I probably have to ask regardless so that I can try my insurance if not, but it would be good to have an idea what to expect)

In case it helps anyone: I did claim and DB did cover the hotel cost, although I'm unsure if that was an unambiguous entitlement or a generous handler. So it's definitely worth trying.

One of my friends was in exactly the same situation before. They tried to claim back their hotel stay with DB together with their delay compensation application (See "Reimbursement of costs for overnight accommodation (e.g. hotel or other accommodation) due to train delays, train cancellations or missed connections in the event of stranding" at https://int.bahn.de/en/booking-information/passenger-rights/legal-regulations), however they were unsuccessful in receiving a reimbursement for the hotel.
However, my personal suggestion would be to nonetheless try, as you are already submitting a delay compensation claim.
